# Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382)

Tags: javascript, mysql

In my JavaScript app I have a code like this that reads some data from a websocket and inserts it into MySQL databae using [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) module:

```
        const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

        const db = await mysql.createConnection(params);

        const ws = new WebSocket(someUrl);

        ws.on('message', (data) =>
        {
            const t = JSON.parse(data);
            //insert some row to MySQL table
            db.execute("INSERT INTO table1 …);
        });
```

periodically the following MySQL error occurs in this code:

```
Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382)
```

My first understanding was that only one statement is executed at a time because there is only one thread in JavaScript and I use only one database connection, but looks like there is a little more complicated mechanism.

What does actually happen? Where multiple statements come from?

**EDIT1:**

Probably mysql2 [caches the statements](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Prepared-Statements.md).

Comment: This count per server so that all prepared variables will be counted from all users. Increase the number to 50000 in my.conf.

Comment: @nbk JavaScript is the only one user with one connection.

Comment: then you have a hell of an insert, my point still stands

Comment: @nbk I need more than 100 inserts per second.